# Mootools code explanation

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am trying to learn Mootools by reading the source and I don't understand why it makes a local copy of Function:

```
var Function = this.Function;
```

but why it doesn't make a local copy of Array, Number and String to do the same, for example they first appear being directly assigned to, so why treat Function differently?

```
Function.from = function(item){
    return (typeOf(item) == 'function') ? item : function(){
        return item;
    };
};

Array.from = function(item){
    if (item == null) return [];
    return (Type.isEnumerable(item) && typeof item != 'string') ? (typeOf(item) == 'array') ? item : slice.call(item) : [item];
};

Number.from = function(item){
    var number = parseFloat(item);
    return isFinite(number) ? number : null;
};

String.from = function(item){
    return item + '';
};
```

Also I don't understand how on line 149 Function calls the implement function which is stored on its local prototype property?

```
Function.implement({

hide: function(){
    this.$hidden = true;
    return this;
},

protect: function(){
    this.$protected = true;
    return this;
}

});
```

is it because Function is a function so its internal [[prototype]] is Function.prototype ?

Comment: Regarding your update for line 149, it's because `implement` is on `Function.prototype`, which automatically makes it available to all functions that have `Function.prototype` in their prototype chain. This includes constructor functions, including the `Function` constructor.

Comment: Do this... `Function.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(Function)` and you'll see that the `Function` instance has its own `prototype` object in its prototype chain. You'll get the same result for functions you create... `Function.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(function(){})` http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.3

Comment: hide/protect are function decorators, used by Class - they allow for methods to become `private` as all function properties in a class constructor object are `wrapped` and if the protected flag is on, it won't let it be called externally etc. these decorators make no sense outside of Class itself. Check out the MooTools `Types` - eg. https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Types/Function.js

Comment: here is an example that will help you understand the difference between sending it to the Function prototype (which makes it a decorator) or the Function type. http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/7LkrS/ - look at console.

Comment: Wow thanks for all your advice and help, you guys are awesome, I'll definately read all the links you have kindly provided me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You'll notice that `Function` is referenced more than the other constructors, so it could be that they added the local reference for a tiny performance boost, as well as for compression since the local variable can be obfuscated. ...*(Taking another look, I do see more references to the other constructors than I originally had.)*
- You'll also notice that the `.overloadSetter()` chained onto the `Function.prototype.extend` function wraps that function with a bunch of extra code, duck typing and such. So the reason they didn't use it was probably that this extra code was apparently unwanted/unneeded for their internal use.
- Because `implement` extends the prototype, it isn't always desirable. Sometimes you just don't want extra methods available on all instances, but you do want to store them in a logical namespace, much like the native methods stored on the `Object` constructor.

Comment: I guess my question was quite bad seen as it's only the devs that wrote it that would really know why they did these things but your answer makes sense and satisfies my curiosity, so thanks.

Comment: local `var` within a closure makes sense and is often used as a mootools pattern. you could probably optimise these a lot better but remember, `mootools-core` actually consists of nearly 30 different files and can be `built` to spec by including only the parts you require. most files come with their own closures (scopes). This makes it harder to macro-optimise variables. it can make sense in smaller closures, esp. in the context of performance-critial stuff--like animations, or class constructors / method decorators etc where repeated / looped references may occur, the gains will add up.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/caching-into-local-scope - check the results. esp in chrome, huge benefits to caching locally.